# User permissions fine-grain control PHP MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am building a web app which users use to assign tasks to each other.

The users are all on a LAN.

There is a basic permissions system already, where user roles are either Admin or normal user.

What I have to implement is something really fine-grained...and I cant think of a good way to do this

Heres a list of things I need to have control over:

1. If a user can change other users info
2. If the user can access the LAN network via VPN(this is another challenge all together, i think)
3. Users can assign tasks to only a set of other users(maybe all, maybe few)
4. If user has the ability to change/delete an already assigned task from another user
5. If the user can delete other users
6. If a user can change other users permissions

What I want is an example of something similar so that I dont have to re-invent the wheel. Or maybe an idea on how to implement this with as little headache as possible :P. Also I dont know how I would structure a MySQL table/s to store all these permissions.

I thought of assigning users roles but I need more flexibility than just those roles.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach is to only have one extra column in the user table, called Access, Permission or something like that. Then for each of the permissions you want you define a constant with a integer value that's dividable by 2, or the number 1, e.g:

```
class PermissionChecker {
  const CAN_CHANGE_OTHER_USERS_INFO = 1; // in bit form: 000001
  const CAN_ACCESS_LAN_VIA_VPN = 2;      //              000010
  const CAN_ASSIGN_TASKS = 4;            //              000100 
  const CAN_CHANGE_OTHER_USERS_TASKS = 8;//              001000
  const CAN_DELETE_USERS = 16;           //              010000
  const CAN_CHANGE_USER_PERMISSIONS = 32;//              100000

  public static function hasAccess($userAccess, $accessFlag) {
    return $userAccess & $accessFlag; // The bitwise operation is the key....
  }
}

$userAccess = 33; // read from database, in bit form: 100001

// check permissions like:

if (PermissionChecker::hasAccess($userAccess, PermissionChecker::CAN_CHANGE_OTHER_USERS_INFO)) {
  // this will be true, because 100001 & 000001 returns 1
}
if (PermissionChecker::hasAccess($userAccess, PermissionChecker::CAN_CHANGE_USER_PERMISSIONS)) {
  // this will be true as well, because 100001 & 100000 returns 1
}
if (PermissionChecker::hasAccess($userAccess, PermissionChecker::CAN_CHANGE_OTHER_USERS_TASKS)) {
  // this will not happen... because 100001 & 001000 returns 0
}
```

Then when another permission level is needed you only have to add another number that's dividable by 2, e.g. 64, 128, etc. Maybe not the prettiest solution, but a simple one.

And when you want to store permissions for a user you use the bitwise-or operator, like:

```
$userAccess = PermissionChecker::CAN_CHANGE_OTHER_USERS_TASKS |
              PermissionChecker::CAN_CHANGE_OTHER_USERS_INFO; // will give $userAccess = 9;
// then store $userAccess in the database for current user...
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a database table to store the permissions where a row is a single permission. If a permission is not present in the table for a given user_id then that user does not have the permission.

```
user_id | permission
-----------------------------
   1    | CHANGE_USER_INFO
   1    | DELETE_USERS
   1    | CHANGE_USER_PERMISSIONS
   2    | VPN_ACCESS
```

As you can see, user 1 would be able to change info, delete and change permissions. User 2 can only access the VPN. This would be easy to add and remove permissions, you'd just need to insert or delete. It would also be easy to create new permission types in future.

To address your point number 3. That one would be more complicated. For that you could have another table with columns `user_id` and `target_user_id` where you would insert the `user_id` of which users can assign tasks to. Alternatively you could add another column to the table above like a generic ID, then insert `ASSIGN_TASK` and populate the ID column with the target user.

Answer (score 0):

Allow the administrator to define roles, as well as define which powers to give each role. That can be done with a bitwise comparison (good), or with a many-to-many relationship database tables (better).

This system gives you most flexibility, as it easily allows you to add new abilities without reconfiguring the whole system of roles.